# Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

Alguien me puede ayudar con este error no se de que se trate!!!
el proyecto completo se encuentra en github:

https://github.com/Austin52/App_Doc

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.austin.app_doc, PID: 14766
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null
>   object reference
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6795)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1816)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1660)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1569)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:888)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19781)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6144)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2674)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2377)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7266)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:981)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:721)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

Este es el código de mi `Adapter` :

```
package com.example.austin.app_doc;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class GrpAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GrpAdaptador.myViewHolder>{

    Context mContext;
    List<GrpItem> mDate;

    public GrpAdaptador(Context mContext, List<GrpItem> mDate) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mDate = mDate;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grp, viewGroup, false);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        myViewHolder.grpEsc.setImageResource(mDate.get(i).getGrpEsc());
        myViewHolder.grpName.setText(mDate.get(i).getGrpName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDate.size();
    }

    public  class myViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView grpEsc;
        TextView grpName;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            grpEsc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.grpEsc);
            grpName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.grpDesc);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Es mejor agregar un poco de tu código, es donde tienes definido un RecyclerView Agrega tu clase GrpAdaptador y te ayudo.

Comment: eh subido donde esta el ReyclearView

Comment: Gracias @AustinArenas acostumbra agregar en tus preguntas información para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de una mejor manera y tus publicaciones sean bien recibidas, (revisar [as]) , he agregado respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigos el error fue solucionado

Comment: Revisa el [tour] @AustinArenas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en el método `onCreateViewHolder()` estas retornado una vista vacía!, como si no desearas desplegar nada... :

```
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grp, viewGroup, false);

    return null;
}
```

En este método debes retornar la vista que inflas.

> [**onCreateViewHolder()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) Se llama cuando RecyclerView necesita un nuevo
>   RecyclerView.ViewHolder del tipo dado para representar un elemento.

esto corregira el problema:

```
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    return new myViewHolder(inflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_grp, viewGroup, false));
}
```